# Is there a way to create custom node types which will never have a page

Tags: nodes

I'm working on several projects where we use custom node types (because they're easy to add fields to, edit, show in views, etc), but there are certain node types I wouldn't want to expose at all in the form of pages, i.e. purely internal (maybe they can be viewed in blocks, at most).

What's the best way to accomplish this?

I am using Drupal 7.

Comment: [Rabbit Hole](http://drupal.org/project/rabbit_hole) is one method...

Comment: First time I've heard of Rabbit Hole, thanks Clive... Rabbit Hole works perfectly for a lot of my usecases, is there anything else?

Comment: If @Clive's suggestion doesn't do what you want, you can always create your own `node--TYPE.tpl.php` and switch on `$type` and `$page` inside it to not display the node contents when/if people surf over to `node/#` on your site.

Comment: That's also valid I guess, but a bit messier.